# Add "last active" time to user profile

Tags: feature-request, last-activity

From my experience *"seen 2 minutes ago"* is not as meaningful as *"active 2 hours ago"*.

Background is the presumption that a lot of users check their inbox or some other interesting profile information via mobile apps and are not really active at this time, e.g. cannot answer questions or give comments.

So why not taking the *"active"* information to the user profile's overview?

Comment: You can see a user's activity from the appropriate tab on their profile already.

Comment: Seems I am the only one around here requesting this feature ;-).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to their profile, and click on the activity tab. The most recent event there will show you the last time they were active.

And, if you go to their stackexchange.com profile, you can see the last time they were active across the network that way.

However, I think that the last seen time is very useful, because even if they can't respond to your question, they can make a note to themselves to respond to it later. Also, it's useful in seeing whether someone checked the site after you answered their question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The last active should not replace the last seen. I know about the activity tab but it would be easier to have it in one click (and going through "earned badge" pseudo activities).

Comment: Accepting this answer for the effort and not only downvoting without a comment. Thanks again.

Comment: @MattHandy I didn't down-vote your question, but thanks anyway. I think the reason why people down-voted was mainly because the feature seemed like it already existed, even though what you technically asked for doesn't. While I wouldn't use your feature-request, I think it has merit, and I think some of those downvotes were unnecessary.